# How to add pop-up window/modal to dynamically created tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="profile">
        <div id='entrydata'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        var dmJSON = "data.json";
        $.getJSON(dmJSON, function(data) {
            $.each(data.records, function(i, f) {
                var $table = "<table border=5><tbody><tr>" + "<td>" + f.Clue + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td>" + f.Answer + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td>" + f.Status + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td> " + f.Views + "</td></tr>" + "</tbody>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</table>"
                $("#entrydata").append($table)
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The above code creates tables dynamically and displays data from my JSON file. I want to make this tables as buttons and add pop up windows to these tables, such that when a table is clicked a pop-up appears and each pop up should have different data. Any solution to this would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: at least show us what have you tried

Comment: In HTML, there is no such, as "modal popup" (except the ugly alert()). You can show up a gray, semi-transparent, full-width and full-height image on the top to gray out existing stuff, and display a div on top of it for your pop-up content. I bet there are lotsa Jquery modules for this purpose.

Comment: are you asking for another ajax call on click and display the date as table in popup?

Comment: No. My table already has pre-defined data. In the pop-up i want to give detailed description of my table data

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: no. the code below display my table on button click. But, i want to add a pop up window to each table

Comment: on click of my table i want its pop up window to appear.

Comment: @LorettaV the idea of stackoverflow is not just to give you code so you can copy and paste and have what you want. It's to help you learn (which is why I pointed you to a library and told you what the most tricky aspect of the problem would be). Your job is to learn from the answers.

Answer (score 0):

The main trick is going to be binding your click handler to the document:

```
$(document).on("click", ".buttonInTd", function() {
    /* give your buttons the 'buttonInTd' class and add your onclick code here */
});
```

Doing this will allow you to dynamically create a table and still capture its events.

To handle modals and popups I would recommend just grabbing one of the multitude of plugins available for that. I really like [featherlight](http://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">

        </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(function() {
                    var dmJSON = "data.json";
                    $.getJSON(dmJSON, function(data) {
                        var $count = 0;
                        $.each(data.records, function(i, f) {
                            var $table = "<button type='button' class='show_btn'>show table" + ++$count + "</button><br><table border=1 class='table_hide'><tbody><tr>" + "<td>" + f.Clue + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td>" + f.Answer + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td>" + f.Status + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td> " + f.Views + "</td></tr>" + "</tbody></table>"
                            $("#entrydata").append($table)
                        });
                        $(".show_btn").click(function() {
                            $(this).next().next().show()
                            $(this).hide();
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            .table_hide {
                display :none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="profile">
                <div id='entrydata'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: my mistake, you are binding after you add to the DOM.